# MVVM User Control Dependency Hell

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

It seems like a straight forward task, i want to pass in a public property value from a MVVM View, but i keep getting the "a 'binding' cannot be set on the property of type . a 'binding' can only be set on a dependencyproperty of a dependencyobject" error.

I am iterate over an observable collection and rendering the item, and i would like to move some Template code into a User control. How the heck can i solve this????

```
<local:xIPAddressControl UserControlIPAddressText="{Binding Path=IPAddress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

#### UserControl

```
public partial class xIPAddressControl : UserControl
{
    public xIPAddressControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    public string UserControlIPAddressText
    {
        get { return this.xIPAddressTextBlock.Text; }
        set { this.xIPAddressTextBlock.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like the error said. Your xIPAdressControl does not contain a DependencyProperty named "UserControlIPAddressText. 

Read here how to do it: http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html

Comment: Check Dependency Property documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0. can this still be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crazy thing, I was trying to set the User control incorrectly. It needs to be the following.

```
//this.DataContext = this;

LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
```

[Tutorial is here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325911/A-Simple-Pattern-for-Creating-Re-useable-UserContr).

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the UserControlIPAddressText as a CLR property, but it needs to be registered with the Dependency Property System.

```
DependencyProperty UserControlIPAddressTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserControlIPADdressText", typeof(string), null);
```

Comment: What i am trying to do here is have a WPF control behave the same way as a .NET web control. Since i have more experience there, i am use to just being able to pass in values through public properties.   I tried to simple try and pass in some text to a WPF User Control, and have that control set a TextBlock, but i'm having issues doing this simple task.

I was getting the DependencyProperty error so, I tried setting up a DepencyProperty, but i still cant get the simple text to set in the control markup.


<TextBlock x:Name="xIPAddressTextBlock"  Text="{Binding IPAddressText}">

Comment: I found the solution above, the user control datacontext was defaulting to the parent control, so the value was not displaying. I changed the Data Context to the LayoutRoot and it all works now.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, your property needs to be a `DependencyProperty` to use a `Binding` on it.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UserControlIPAddressTextProperty=
            DependencyProperty.Register("UserControlIPAddressText",
                                        typeof(string),
                                        typeof(xIPAddressControl));

       public string UserControlIPAddressText
       {
           get { return (string)GetValue(UserControlIPAddressTextProperty); }
           set { SetValue(UserControlIPAddressTextProperty, value); }
       }
```